# unable to persist indexedDB after reinstallation

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, google-chrome-app

I am unable to persist indexedDB when I re-install the chrome app which is using it. While I'm able to persist data using the sync file system across re-installations.

1. Should I use the storage API to push the indexedDB data in an array and store it in a file?
2. Is there a "C language" like way in JS(while making chrome app) to save data using structs and file access? Something like data structures using JS.
3. Am I going all wrong? And the solution to this problem is rather simple and obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you get for app is the app sandbox and resources also using in the app sandbox. Chrome delete the sandbox and it resources after app was removed. And it's true behavior then you create a sandbox.

You need any back-end/server-side storage to store use data and sync it then user reinstall the app.

Comment: I'm able to persist data using the sync file system across re-installations.

Comment: You can't get access to real `file system` from browser. You can use [`LocalFileSystem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem) which is also works in the sandbox.